# How to fit web page to webview's width when webview resizes (without reloading)

Tags: android, webview, resize, orientation

I have an HTML page and a full-screen Android webview. The HTML content is larger than the webview's visible area. I *want* to fit the HTML content to the width of webview.

What's really important is this: when the device's orientation changes, the webview will not reload, meaning it will just resize and the content would still *fit* to width.

One more thing: because the content has been scaled down, user can zoom it in to a maximum scale of 100%. When the content is zoomed and orientation changes, I *want* the content to fit-width again.

*Edit 1*: I can change meta tags in the head of HTML, but its content remains larger than the webview's visible area. I'm supporting Android 2.3 and later.

*Edit 2*: Thanks for the suggestion on responsive web design. I know what it is and I can do it. Problem is I cannot change much of the HTML content in this case.

**TL;DR**: How to always fit a larger HTML content to a Android webview's width as the webview resizes, without reloading the content. (I can change the webview, not much of the HTML.)

Comment: Some pictures for reference: when webview first loads, overview mode works [well](http://imgur.com/tDqaYIV) but when orientation changes, the page is not rendered in overview mode [anymore](http://imgur.com/rgzwH3V)

Answer (score 20):

do following settings

```
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that already but it would only work when the page first loads; when the device's orientation changes (webview resizes) the page would not fit-width any more.

Comment: can paste some sample snap shots

Comment: Here you are: when page first loads, overview mode works well http://imgur.com/tDqaYIV but when orientation changes, the page is not rendered in overview mode anymore http://imgur.com/rgzwH3V

Comment: it requires responsive theme from html source. We solved it using same.

Answer (score 5):

This may sound like a cop-out answer, but I think it depends on how you're building the rest of your site. Whenever I work on responsive sites, I use:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

This will do two things: `width=device-width` will find the width of your device, and send styles from your CSS that match that size (you can set styles for specific sizes in your CSS, using media queries). `Initial-scale=1` will make the site show up at 100% when it loads, but still give users the option to zoom in.

If your site is developed for a specific width, you could try using:

`<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = 980 (or whatever the width you're designing for)">`

This will just scale down your site to fit the device width. Nothing super special here, users will basically just be shown mini-desktop sites.

I'd recommend reading this [Webdesign Tuts+](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/) article. They explain the viewport meta tag well, with examples.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm doing and it works when the page first loads -- but my problem is when the webview resizes (device's orientation changes), the page is not fit-width anymore. Do you have any idea for that?

Comment: @HoangHuynh When you load the page with the device already rotated, does it load alright? I know for some older iOS devices there was a bug where things didn't resize on rotate, so it could be something similar.  
If that doesn't work, are you able to edit the CSS, or link to an external CSS file? You may need to fiddle around with how it's built.

Answer (score 2):

> You need not change anything on Webview , all u need is Responsive
>   Html Page, If you are designer then that will solve ur issue or u can
>   post a part of ur Question with UI tag.
>
> To built Responsive html pages u can visit : [HERE](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design)
>
> Result : You need to test on webview while creating your responsive
>   html page, default brower of android itself reflect that ur html page
>   is responsive or not.Once it will work in default brower in Android
>   device then it will work in any webview in android.
>
> Testing : you can test ur responsive html page [HERE](http://www.responsinator.com/)

Comment: Thanks Monica, I know Reponsive HTML but the current HTML content that I have to display in a webview is not responsive and I need to use the zoom function of webview to scale it down.

Comment: The thing is I _cannot_ change much of the HTML content (I can change the meta tags in `<head>` though).

Answer (score 0):

I would have to see the source of your HTML and CSS. You have to exclusively use % sizes and never use fixed width px sizes. Then, the user can change the size of the browser and it will dynamically resize. I also use % widths because of this. It also dynamically resizes if you use CTRL-MouseWheel (zoom).

Comment: Too bad I cannot change my HTML and it uses absolute px. Both the width and height of HTML are larger than those of my device's. I need to zoom the whole page down to fit it into the sreen estate.

Comment: Sorry you won't be able to do it with fixed widths. You can embed your page into an iframe that is the proper size and use scroll bars or you can experiment with CSS scale transforms. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#funcdef-scale

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip for responsive web design, use positions instead of widths:

For example:

**html**

```
<div id="somediv">I'm just a div, just a regular div.</div>
```

**css**

```
#somediv {
left: 0; /*numeric value in pixels you would like this div to be from the left */
right: 0; /*same as above, except on the right */
height: 50px;
width: auto;
}
```

The div above will automatically resize based on screen width.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Too bad I cannot change much of the HTML and it uses absolute px. Both the width and height of HTML are larger than those of my device's. I need to zoom the whole page down to fit it into the sreen estate.