# Android WebView Responsive While Zooming

Tags: android, webview, responsive-design

The font size and image in the WebView are able to zoom, but not responsive to screen. It is expected to fit on the width of 100%. It is not applicable on Android 5.0 Lollipop and above. I tried on Kitkat device, it worked. I'm wondering what should I do in order to make it works on 5.0 and above.

I did configure the meta tag of the webpage:

`< meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`

The following configurations are what I have applied on the webview:

```
WebView wv1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
wv1.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

wv1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

wv1.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

wv1.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

wv1.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

wv1.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

wv1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

wv1.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674376/how-to-fit-web-page-to-webviews-width-when-webview-resizes-without-reloading

Comment: Thanks, Zain. I did that already but it would only work when the page first loads; when the device's orientation changes (webview resizes) the page would not fit-width any more.